# How to create a block component where it should have radio button, chart and then text message and top right corner close button?

Tags: angular, angular7

You can refer to the image attached.

How to create a block component where it should have a **radio button**, **chart** and then **text message** and top right corner **close button**?

This component should be created as many times as we can, each time we click on the drop down? 
**the count of the box at max should have 6. In case you are making click to drop down again, you should first close at least one of the block.**

Any help would be appreciated?
Thanks

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7F3qf.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you getting stuck?
Can you share some code?

Comment: Zaief:  This what I created as block component:<div>
    <input class="rd" type="radio" checked/><small>Low</small>
    <input class="rd" type="radio"/><small>Medium</small>
    <input class="rd" type="radio"/><small>High</small>
    <input class="rd" type="radio"/><small>NA</ small>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="closing1(closeable1)">
        <span aria-hidden="true">x</span>
    </button>
      <hr>
    <div style="width:98%;" [chart]="stock2"></div>
  </div>

Comment: How to make it dynamic, That means, if you clicking on drop down 7 times, you need to first delete any of the blocks.